# Get bare file names recursively in command prompt

Tags: command-line, filenames, recursive

I ran into a little snag trying to get only the filenames (no extensions or file paths) recursively.This worked for me in the root folder:

```
dir /b
```

But when i added /s to scan recursively i also got file paths before filenames which i do not want.
Is there a way to get bare filenames from all subfolders in a directory?

Im on Windows 7 x64
I'd rather use regular command prompt not PS or VBS

Answer (score 16):

Use the following command:

```
dir /b /a /s
```

- **/b** strips the date and other details from the output
- **/a** only outputs the filename, no paths
- **/s** enables a recursive directory listing

If you need to save the output to a file, you can use:

```
dir /b /a /s >> list_of_names.txt
```

EDIT
Actually the above solution doesn't reach the original question's goals. One thing I did notice from the question is that the post asks for recursive listing. which the other answer lacks so I think adding "/s" in the other answerer's answer will do the trick

```
for /f %a in ('dir /b /s') do @echo %~na
```

Comment: Could you explain this? To me it makes little sense.

Comment: This doesn't work, /a doesn't work like that - it's a filter for which type of files you want to list. It doesn't strip the path from the filename when doing a recursive directory listing.

Comment: edited the answer; and just got my hands on a windows box again, I think this time should do it (win732bit)

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
for /f "delims=" %a in ('dir /b /s') do @echo %~na
```

More information on how for works and what it's doing, type `for /?`

Comment: This almost works but there's a big problem.It only outputs the first word of a filename.If a filename is for example "my vacation image 1" then it only outputs "my"

Comment: try this: for /f "delims=|" %a in ('dir /b') do @echo %~na. By default the /f parameter of FOR will tokenize on spaces. Setting the token to a character that shouldn't appear in file/directory names will give you the entire name including spaces.

Comment: If you want the output sent to a file, append `>> filename.txt`

Answer (score 2):

```
for /r %i in (*) do @echo %~ni
```

or

```
forfiles /s /c "cmd /c if @isdir==FALSE noquotes.bat @fname"
```

assuming a file `noquotes.bat` in your [%PATH%](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them) with this content

```
@echo %~1
```

**for /r approach explained**

`for /r` walks the current directory recursively (you can specify a directory `for /r drive:\path\`, the current directory is assumed) and executes the command specified by do for each file matched in the set `(*)`. The set `(.)` would match only directories. @echo %~ni
This command works as-is from the prompt. Double up on your quotes if you put it inside a batch file. i.e. `for /r %%i in (*) do @echo %%~ni`

**forfiles approach explained**

`/s` enumerates the current and all subdirectories
`/c` executes the command inside the quotes
`@isdir` and `@fname` is a symbol emitted into the command string
The extra batch file `noquotes.bat` helps by stripping the double-quotes with %~1 (parameter 1)
`forfiles` also allows you to specify a path to start at `forfiles /P C:\Windows ...`

Comment: @DavidPostill yes, it was a poor answer. Thanks for your comments. Please let me know if I can improve my answer further.

Comment: @DavidPostill you have no previous answer or comment. were you moderating questions, or looking for an answer and stumble over my poor quality answer?

Comment: Your answer popped up in the "Low Quality Posts" review queue. As I know a lot about batch files I took a close at it.

Comment: @DavidPostill thanks for your review. I welcome your review of the changes I made to my answer.

Comment: Much better ... :)

Answer (score -1):

List all files, bare, recursively, using attributes (not directory) (files only)

dir /B /S /A:-D

C:\test\cache>dir /B /S /A:-D

C:\test\cache\7\0f\7b50ed0522645513da90345120eaf0f7
C:\test\cache\d\23\814644aa6a8195c91e54d2f7bb64e23d

Comment: The question says that the OP is “trying to get only the filenames (no extensions or file paths).  …  But when I [tried `dir /b /s`] to scan recursively, I also got file paths before filenames, which I do not want.” So, you are telling the OP to try a trivial variation on what they’ve already tried, and your answer demonstrates that it produces the same result as when the OP tried it (i.e., not what they want).