# How do I recursively list filenames (only) in DOS/Windows?

Tags: windows-xp, command-line, filenames, dir

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get bare file names recursively in command prompt](https://superuser.com/questions/294099/get-bare-file-names-recursively-in-command-prompt)

I would like to recursively list all files in a directory, showing filenames only (without extensions and without the full paths). I'm using Windows/DOS.

The closest I could get with `dir` was `dir /s /b`, but it lists full paths and also shows the extensions.

Well, perhaps I could live with the extensions, but I must get rid of the paths!

Any ideas?

Comment: Which version of windows?

Comment: @OldWolf: XP. I prefer not to use any third-party software/

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
cd /d C:\Path\To\Source\Folder
for /r %i in (*) do @echo %~ni
```

If you need the list saved to a file, append `>> C:\Path\To\list_file.txt` to the end of the `for` command.

If you end up wanting the extensions, change `%~ni` to `%~nxi`

To use in a batch file, change all the `%` to `%%`

Comment: If you need path and name and extension, change %~ni to %~pnxi

Comment: this works but it doesn't show hidden files. How can I also see the hidden files?

Comment: @ala: If you want to show hidden files, you'll need to use something like [David Remy's answer](http://superuser.com/a/344170/34636) only with the appropriate flags passed to the `dir` command.

Answer (score 8):

If you are willing to load powershell, this command should do it.

```
get-childitem "d:\acc" -recurse|foreach {$_.Basename}
```

Answer (score 5):

Doing something like the following should get you what you want:

`@for /f "delims=" %a in ('Dir /s /b %systemdrive%') do echo %~na`

Just pipe the output to a file and use it from there if needed.

Answer (score 3):

Don't know if you'd consider it a 3rd party software or not since it's form Microsoft and ships with 7, but powershell will solve most of your problem pretty easily. If you haven't already installed it, it's available for XP on Microsoft's site.

```
Get-ChildItem -path "C:\Program Files\" -recurse | foreach ($_) {
    write $_.name
}
```