# Detect duplicate file name with different extension

Tags: command-line, batch, microsoft-office, duplicate

I used [Office File Converter (OFC)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2008/09/19/bulk-convert-doc-to-docx.aspx) to convert my old Office documents to the newer format with a an X (docx, xlsx, pptx). OFC did not provide an option to delete converted documents. Now, I need to traverse through my documents folder to find duplicate file names but with a different extension. For example, my Word document with a name of **superuser.doc** will also have a converted copy called **superuser.docx**.

Comment: This tool have option choose output directory for docx files. I don't see point in this question. If you want delete old doc. Simple find all *.doc in input directory and delete them. Since this old doc now docx in different(output) directory. If you want delete docx delete output directory...

Comment: He problem is that sometimes the files do not convert, so if I blindly delete a doc, there may not be an equivalent docx file. I understand your point though... In general, that idea will work if all files convert without issue.

Comment: [Try search doc in input directory and docx in output directory,sort and save them](http://superuser.com/questions/344155/how-do-i-recursively-list-filenames-only-in-dos-windows). [In docx list need remove last character on every lane](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21640713/notepad-how-to-remove-last-character-on-every-line)(this need for compare). Then try use [Notepad++ Compare](http://www.davidtan.org/how-to-compare-two-text-files-using-notepad-plus/) or [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org) for find differences between this lists.

Answer (score 1):

This is really very easy in PowerShell. I am providing you with a script that searches the current folder and its subfolders for files with `.docx`, `.xlsx` and `.pptx` extensions, then deletes all files with the same name but with `.doc`, `.xls` and `.ppt` extensions.

**The responsibility of navigating to the right folder before running this script lies with you.**

```
Get-ChildItem *.docx,*.xlsx,*.pptx -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
  $filePath = $_.FullName
  $filePath = $filePath.TrimEnd("x")
  Remove-Item $filePath
}
```

I deliberately used multiple lines and full readable names to make the script understandable. (I could make it a one-liner.) But copying and pasting it whole into PowerShell **is supported! :)**

Comment: `$a` wasn't really clear but otherwise a really nice approach!

Comment: Damn it, knew I forgot something. That comment was just there in case you were wondering about the edit.

Comment: @Seth Nah. It was obviously a good edit. If I use full command names, I might as well give meaningful names to variables too.