# Finding only shortcuts that point to a certain machine

Tags: windows-7, shortcuts, file-shortcut

I have 100s of short-cuts in various folders on my C: drive.  (Windows 7)

Many point to folders on another machine called JANICE1.

Countless others point to JANICE2.

The remainder point to folders on my local computer.

What is the quickest way to find all the JANICE2 shortcuts?

(I can't even figure out how to list "all shortcuts" only, let alone "only JANICE2 shortcuts".)

I'm currently selecting every short-cut, 1-by-1, and hitting PROPERTIES and checking them
manually.  Ugh.  There's got to be a better way.

Comment: this can easily be done with a script (vbs/powershell). Is that an option for you? what would you want to do with the shortcuts after you found them?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work, from the DOS prompt, though the output is somewhat messy:

`for /r %i in (*.lnk) do @find /N "JANICE2" %i`

[Hat tip](https://superuser.com/a/344160/128566)

---

Better seems to be:

`@echo off`
 `for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir *.lnk /b /s') do (`
 `for /f "delims=" %%b in ('find "JANICE2" ^<"%%a" ^|find /c /v "" ') do (`
 `if %%b GTR 1 >>"foundJANICE2.txt" echo %%a`
 `)`
 `)`

Copy it to a file - like *searchJANICE2.bat* and run it from the CMD.

Your answer will be in foundJANICE2.txt

[Hat tip](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3231)